# Firebase Firestore Query help android stuido java

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok so here is my problem. I have created a firestore database called "users" and I have added to everyone the UID from the authentication and a username that they can choose. I want to display their username onto a textfield.

So I did:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference noteRef;

String currentUid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
noteRef = db.collection("users");
Query query = noteRef.whereEqualTo("uid", currentUid);
```

but now I am clueless... So first I took put the currentUser UID that is logged into the app and want to search in my firestore database in "users" for an entry with that same UID so I did this query. The problem is how can I get now the username ? The query is delivering the entry that I am looking for I think but how can I get now the username ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user name is stored as a field in the user's document, you can get it with:

```
query.get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData().get("username"));
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

For some more examples of this, see the Firebase documentation on [executing a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

---

Note that it is common store the user's documents with the UID as their key, which makes it a bit easier to look them up.

To store the documents like this, you'd do something like:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore.getInstxance()
    .collection("users")
    .document(uid)
    .set(...)
```

And then you'd get it with:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstxance()
    .collection("users")
    .document(uid)
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

You'll note that we now no longer need the loop that we had earlier, as we're getting one specific document instead of needing a query to find the document(s) for the user.